# How to verify ashref, semrush and uptime.com bot (crawler)

Tags: php, dns, web-crawler, reverse-dns

To verify google bot should do this:

> Run a reverse DNS lookup on the accessing IP address from your logs,
>   using the host command.
>       Verify that the domain name is in either googlebot.com or google.com
>       Run a forward DNS lookup on the domain name retrieved in step 1 using the host command on the retrieved domain name. Verify that it is
>   the same as the original accessing IP address from your logs.

But what should I do to verify other bots like ashref, semrush and uptime.com? The reverse domain return meaningless host like `ip170.ip-54-36-149.eu`

I want to block any unverified bot. So is there any way to verify those?

Comment: What is a "verified" bot?

Comment: To verify that it belongs to the company not just spoof it's user agent.